# How to pass value from portal-ext.properties to ilferay-portlet.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, liferay

I am using liferay.

> I need to get some variable from portal-ext.properties in
>   liferay-portal.xml file. How can I get those values? Can I made some
>   my custom java class form where I can get value of some parameter
>   there?

Comment: Do you want to transport portal-ext.properties to liferay-portal.xml? Why?

Comment: @Mark Previously, I have maintained the js files in footer section of liferay-portlet.xml. Now I have moved the js into cdn and hence I want to change the url of the js files. I have custom url property in portal-ext.properties. How can I read the url from portal-ext.properties in liferay-portlet.xml? Is there any other alternative that fits my purpose?

Comment: I had similar requirement and we set a symbolic link from CDN to ~/tomcat/webapps/res. Thereby we have the same url for all servers.

Comment: I have similar problem How do you achieve that?

Comment: We had implemented CDN on liferay way. i.e placing cdn url on protal-ext.properties file.

Answer (score 3):

First, there is no mechanism to achieve exactly what you ask for (none that I know of at least).

For the underlying problem that you state in your comment, you might want to check how many CSS files are actually downloaded from your portal: Typically Liferay minifies JS and CSS files and delivers them from cache, with proper caching headers - and it delivers only one file of each, combining all the referenced files (correct me if that's wrong - careful, don't look at developer mode where the minifier is explicitly turned off)

If you deliver all individual portlet's header files from CDN you might end up with 10 individual requests to CDN which might end up slower than a single minified request/response to your own portal.

My advice would be to first measure performance manually (e.g. measure local files, then reference CDN location manually and measure again).

There might be something in Liferay's API that you can override during the initialization phase, when you can programatically read the configured values, but I haven't checked this yet. Also, please make sure that the minifier doesn't go out to the CDN to fetch the resources in order to minify them and deliver them from the portal. This would be counterproductive and just add complexity to your system.

And lastly, for your specific system, you could also just "always include" the CDN resources on every page (add them to your theme) and have your portlets assume that they are included. This works well if you have only plugins that you develop yourself, not if you develop plugins for others.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. :) We solved this problem in liferay way by adding cdn.host.http url on portal-ext.properties file.